# Is there a Dark Theme for Visual Studio 2017 that is similar to Microsoft Docs "Dark Mode"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, themes, microsoft-documentation

I'm trying to find a color theme for Visual Studio that is similar to the look and feel of Microsoft Docs' "Dark Mode" (learn.microsoft.com). I think it would add a nice coding experience when working side-by-side with Microsoft Docs website.

I tried to look at github.com/Microsoft/VS-ColorThemes
and studiostyl.es but no luck yet.

[Color theme target - dark mode in Microsoft Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUM2D.png)

Sample MS Docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?view=netcore-2.2

Comment: There is a plugin tool for VS called "Color Editor for Visual Studio 2017" that can be added via Visual Studio's Extensions and Updates item in the Tools menu. This will install a bunch of additional themes as well as provide a way to import a custom theme.

Answer (score 3):

you can change visual studio theme by Tools menu. 
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General.

change `Color theme:` Combo box.

Comment: Default VS color themes and those at github.com/Microsoft/VS-ColorThemes are not similar to the dark mode theme in learn.microsoft.com